# Случайные значения с разными вероятностями

Tags: java, minecraft

разработчики. Мне нужно сделать выдачу случайных предметов. Как это реализовать я знаю, и всё работает отлично. Но нужно сделать то же самое, но с шансами. Как это сделать?
Шансы передаются в конфиге, таким видом:

> **- 'ПРЕДМЕТ:50'**

Где 50 - Шанс.
Если что, предметы у меня хранятся в ArrayList

```
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
items.add("DIAMOND_SWORD");
items.add("STONE");
items.add("GOLDEN_APPLE");
```

Нужно неограниченное количество предметов, так как в пример я привёл лишь несколько
Пытался делать через Math.random(), но не вышло

Comment: Строишь накопительную сумму шансов. Генерируешь случайное от нуля до максимума этой суммы. Выбираешь то, в чей диапазон попало число.

Comment: opt1 1 -10, opt2 - 11 - 50, opt3 51 - 100 и генеришь число от 1 до 100 и смотришь куда попало

Answer (score 0):

Допустим это наш конфиг.

```
Map<String, Integer> config = Map.of(
    "DIAMOND_SWORD", 10,
    "STONE", 70,
    "GOLDEN_APPLE", 20
);
```

Развернем конфиг наоборот. В качестве ключа будем использовать
накопительную сумму шансов (шансы текущего предмета + всех предыдущих), о которой говорит [@Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229437/akina), а значением будет название предмета. Но поместим их не в HashMap, а в TreeMap, т.к. он позволит искать не конкретный ключ, а ближайший больший.

```
NavigableMap<Integer, String> chances = new TreeMap<>();
int chancesSum = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : config.entrySet()) {
    String item = entry.getKey();
    Integer chance = entry.getValue();
    chancesSum += chance;
    chances.put(chancesSum, item);
}
// {70=STONE, 80=DIAMOND_SWORD, 100=GOLDEN_APPLE}
// от 0 до 70 - STONE
// от 71 до 80 - DIAMOND_SWORD
// от 81 до 100 - GOLDEN_APPLE
```

Осталось сгенерировать случайное число в диапазоне [0..100] и получить нужный предмет:

```
chances.ceilingEntry(random.nextInt(runningSum + 1)).getValue();
// ceilingEntry ищет в TreeMap ближайший ключ, равный или больший указанного.
// +1 нужен, т.к. nextInt генерирует число строг оменьше заданного ограничения
```

Проверить, что реализация работает как надо, можно вызвав генератор много раз
и посчитав, сколько раз сгененировался каждый предмет:

```
Map<String, Integer> check = new HashMap<>();
Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    String result = chances.ceilingEntry(random.nextInt(runningSum + 1)).getValue();
    check.put(result, check.getOrDefault(result, 0) + 1);
}
System.out.println(check);
//{GOLDEN_APPLE=178, DIAMOND_SWORD=104, STONE=718}
```